# Why Parse server is creating new object instead of updating?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I am running parse server in NodeJS environment with express.

Generally, Parse automatically figures out which data has changed so only “dirty” fields will be sent to the Parse Cloud. So, I don’t need to worry about squashing data that I didn’t intend to update.

But why this following code is saving new data every time instead of updating the existing document data with name "Some Name".

```
// Parse code

Parse.initialize(keys.parseAppID);
Parse.serverURL = keys.parseServerURL;

var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("GameScore");
var gameScore = new GameScore();

let data = {
    playerName: "Some Name",
    score: 2918,
    cheatMode: true
};



gameScore.save(data, {
            success: (gameScore) => {
                // let q = new Parse.Query("GameScore");
                // q.get(gameScore.id)
                console.log("ID: " + gameScore.id)

            },
            error: function (gameScore, error) {
                // Execute any logic that should take place if the save fails.
                // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
                alert('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + error.message);
            }
        });




// End of Parse code
```

Comment: Hey @perception30, if my answer worked for you could you mark it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're executing the query to find which object you want to update, but then you're not using the results when you go to save `data`.

```
query.first({ // This will result in just one object returned
    success: (result) => { 
        // Check to make sure a result exists
        if (result) {
            result.save(data, {
                // Rest of code
```

Note: You're treating `playerName` as a unique key. If multiple users can have the same `playerName` attribute, then there will be bugs. You can use `id` instead which is guaranteed to be unique. If you use `id` instead, you can utilize [`Parse.Query.get`](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/classes/Parse.Query.html#methods_get)

Edit: 
Since you want to update an existing object, you must specify its id.

```
var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("GameScore");
var gameScore = new GameScore();
gameScore.id = "ID"; // This id should be the id of the object you want to update
```

Comment: I just updated the code. please review.
This should update the existing object instead of creating a new object every time I run the code.
But It is creating a new duplicate object every time instead of updating existing one.

Comment: using a unique key like id/email does not solve the issue as well.

Comment: What existing object? You're not fetching any object from the database.

Comment: My Parse server (mongodb database) has an existing document object with exactly same data.

Comment: It doesn't have the same id though.

Comment: even if I use the same ID, the result is still same.

Comment: It's because you haven't fetched the object. You were closer with your code before you changed your question. Currently you're just saving raw data and Parse cannot know that it maps to an existing object.

Comment: Parse should automatically figures out which data has changed so only "dirty" fields will be sent to the Parse Cloud. You don't need to worry about squashing data that you didn't intend to update.

http://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#updating-objects

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152337/discussion-between-dehli-and-perception30).

Comment: Your code does not set `gameScore.id`.  You can have multilpe objects with the same data but different ids. If you set the id on the object shell, it'll save that specific object. But if you save an object shell that has no id, it assumes you're trying to save a new object. You MUST set the id of the object.

Comment: Yup! He changed the question which is why I added the edit. @JakeT.